# Decoding empty JSON string value into nil with Decodable

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

Suppose I have a struct like this:

```
struct Result: Decodable {
   let animal: Animal?
}
```

And an enum like this:

```
enum Animal: String, Decodable {
   case cat = "cat"
   case dog = "dog"
}
```

but the JSON returned is like this:

```
{
  "animal": ""
}
```

If I try to use a `JSONDecoder` to decode this into a `Result` struct, I get `Cannot initialize Animal from invalid String value` as an error message. How can I properly decode this JSON result into a `Result` where the animal property is nil?

Comment: In your case, the animal in JSON is not nil. Neither it is of type Animal. It is of string type. It is just an empty String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to treat an empty string as `nil`, you need to implement your own decoding logic. For example:

```
struct Result: Decodable {
    let animal: Animal?

    enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case animal
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let string = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .animal)

        // here I made use of the fact that an invalid raw value will cause the init to return nil
        animal = Animal.init(rawValue: string)
    }
}
```